# Structs and scruct arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Hi! I have a problem with my code here. When I try to access this scruct array i have, it won't let me access the actual array space *i*, but rather it gives me the same array values over and over until it's done. Do any of you see the error? This is a relatively short except out of my code, the names of the functions are correct, don't worry about that. However, whenever I try to use draw_boxes, it will only ever give me position 0 of boxes[], the first in the array boxes[]; no more, and thereby not giving out what i want. Please keep in mind that I'm an IT student in his first semester, with no previous experience in programming in c++. Something that might be obvious to you isn't gonna be as obvious to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#define CIMGGIP_MAIN
#include "CImgGIP05.h"
using namespace std;

struct Box
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int delta_y;
};

const int box_max = 10, box_size = 40;


void draw_boxes(Box boxes[])
{


    white_background();

    for (int i = 0; i < box_max; i++)
    {
        gip_draw_rectangle(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, box_size, box_size,
            blue);
        /* don't mind this, it's something we had in our given header file.
        This line is correct*/
    }
}

int main() {

    Box boxes[box_max] = { 0 };



    for (int i = 0; i < box_max; i++)
    {
        boxes[i].x = i * (box_size + 20) + 10;
        boxes[i].y = 0;
        boxes[i].delta_y = random(10, 30);
    }

    draw_boxes(boxes);

    return 0;
}
```

When I use the function draw_boxes(), i want it to cycle through my array of boxes[], and not just use one.

The result I get is a syntax error. It will only ever use a single space of boxes[], even though I give it the indexes for the other spaces, so it only works with one set of values.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What syntax error to you get? When asking a question about an error, it's important to share the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Your life will be easier if you use `std::vector` rather than arrays.

Comment: sadly, i HAVE to use the vector for now. Our professor won't let us use anything else at the moment

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: If you get a syntax error, you shouldn't see any boxes at all since the program didn't compile.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have looked at the debugger for a while, and before i use the draw_boxes, The struct array boxes[] is correct, and as soon as I go into draw_boxes it only takes the first entry, so boxes[0] and uses those values over and over. It's not an error, technically, but not what i want it to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo This isn't the entire program, this is only the part that's giving me problems

Comment: @KidKAt So does the program you posted have a syntax error, or does it have the problem of only drawing one box?

Comment: @KidKAt If you are relying on the debugger to see what `boxes` contains in `void draw_boxes(Box boxes[])` it will likely only show you the first element. The debugger likely relies on the type of `boxes` to figure out how to display it to you and has no way to deduce the number of elements `boxes` contains from it's type. Please print out to console the positions of the boxes being drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, but your logic is likely wrong.

Your function gip_draw_rectangle is likely:

```
gip_draw_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,color);
```

where you want `x2 = x1 + width; and y2 = y1 + height;`
Your boxes simply overlap. Last one is drawn over all.

try with:

```
gip_draw_rectangle(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].x + box_size, boxes[i].y + box_size, blue);
```

Comment: You're assuming it's not `gip_draw_rectangle(x, y, width, height, color);`.

Comment: yes, exactly. otherwise he's code goes as expected through all the items of the array.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I guess I just understood the function wrong, since the header file we got isn't documented at all! This fixed it!

Comment: nice to hear. Then you could validate the answer. Good luck!